# Sending SOL from one wallet to another never arrives

Tags: rust, solana

I'm trying to send SOL from one account to another in the Devnet using system_instruction::transfer but the funds never move from the wallet_a to wallet_b. Am I missing something? The wallet A has 1.5 solana.

I also tried to use the private key in the sender but didn't work.

https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens

```
use solana_sdk::signer::keypair::Keypair;
use solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use std::{str::FromStr};
use solana_program::{pubkey::Pubkey};
use solana_program::{system_instruction};

fn main () {
    let wallet_a = "DVJM5LZEMWwypvgBRysQBUKXE6Jc2wqDcJouGerZnbZz";
    let wallet_b = "9c6YTLYHxnRzvQtUwd41qGUBhdSWkGJFtedbxWg8D6eZ";
    let from : Pubkey = Pubkey::from_str(&wallet_a).unwrap();
    let dest : Pubkey = Pubkey::from_str(&wallet_b).unwrap();
    let amount : u64 =  1000000000;
    send_sol (&from, &dest, amount);
}

fn send_sol (from_wallet: &Pubkey, to_wallet: &Pubkey, amount: u64) { 
    println!("From: {} to: {}", from_wallet, to_wallet);
    let result = system_instruction::transfer(from_wallet, to_wallet, amount);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

This is the output:

```
From: DVJM5LZEMWwypvgBRysQBUKXE6Jc2wqDcJouGerZnbZz to: 9c6YTLYHxnRzvQtUwd41qGUBhdSWkGJFtedbxWg8D6eZ
Instruction { program_id: 11111111111111111111111111111111, accounts: [AccountMeta { pubkey: DVJM5LZEMWwypvgBRysQBUKXE6Jc2wqDcJouGerZnbZz, is_signer: true, is_writable: true }, AccountMeta { pubkey: 9c6YTLYHxnRzvQtUwd41qGUBhdSWkGJFtedbxWg8D6eZ, is_signer: false, is_writable: true }], data: [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 202, 154, 59, 0, 0, 0, 0] }
```

Comment: Consider asking future questions on the solana stack exchange: https://solana.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

So, all's you've done within you `send_sol` function is generate the instruction to send SOL. You need to put that instruction in a `Transaction` and then sign/send using the `RpcClient`:

```rust
    let rpc_url = String::from("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
    let connection = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(rpc_url, CommitmentConfig::confirmed());

    ///Airdropping some Sol to the 'from' account
    match connection.request_airdrop(&frompubkey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL) {
        Ok(sig) => loop {
            if let Ok(confirmed) = connection.confirm_transaction(&sig) {
                if confirmed {
                    println!("Transaction: {} Status: {}", sig, confirmed);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        Err(_) => println!("Error requesting airdrop"),
    };

    ///Creating the transfer sol instruction
    let ix = system_instruction::transfer(&frompubkey, &topubkey, lamports_to_send);

    ///Putting the transfer sol instruction into a transaction
    let recent_blockhash = connection.get_latest_blockhash().expect("Failed to get latest blockhash.");
    let txn = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(&[ix], Some(&frompubkey), &[&from], recent_blockhash);

    ///Sending the transfer sol transaction
    match connection.send_and_confirm_transaction(&txn){
        Ok(sig) => loop {
            if let Ok(confirmed) = connection.confirm_transaction(&sig) {
                if confirmed {
                    println!("Transaction: {} Status: {}", sig, confirmed);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        Err(e) => println!("Error transferring Sol:, {}", e),
    }
```

Comment: Where the [&from] is coming from? solana_sdk::signature::Signer?

Comment: It is just a pubkey